# Improving query (Doing a nasty self join on a range with ctes)

Tags: mysql, mariadb, join, cte, self-join

```
-- The CTE1 is just to create columns that dictate the bound of what is considered the same entry
-- Also I do a dense rank by ACT_TIME, and a PARITION BY on ID1, ID2
-- so all ID1/ID2 combos are ranked by when they ran
WITH 
cte1 AS (SELECT *, (X-2) AS X_START, (X+2) AS X_END, (Y-2) AS Y_START, (Y+2) AS Y_END, (Z*1.2) AS Z_MAX,
    DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY ID1, ID2 ORDER BY ACT_TIME) AS DENSE_RANK
    FROM data
    ORDER BY data.ACT_TIME)

,cte2 AS (
-- Create new set of column as comparisons
SELECT 
ID AS ID_COMP,
ID1 AS ID1_COMP,
ID2 AS ID2_COMP,
X_START AS X_START_COMP,
X_END AS X_END_COMP,
Y_START AS Y_START_COMP,
Y_END AS Y_END_COMP,
Z AS Z_MAX_COMP,
DENSE_RANK AS DENSE_RANK_COMP
FROM cte1)
, cte3 AS (
-- join cte1 on cte2 only when X and Y value from cte1 is between the limits of cte2 AND 
-- Z max value from cte 2 is larger than Z value from cte1 AND ID1/ID2 match
-- The result will have an ID of a row that should be removed since their x and y was in between the limits 
-- Then remove any rows where rank from cte2 is higher than cte1
--  Remove any rows that were joined onto it self 
SELECT 
cte1.* ,
cte2.*
FROM cte1
JOIN cte2 ON (( cte2.X_END_COMP >= cte1.X  AND  cte1.X >= cte2.X_START_COMP) AND (cte2.Y_END_COMP >= cte1.Y AND cte1.Y>= cte2.Y_START_COMP) 
                    AND (cte1.Z < cte2.Z_MAX_COMP) AND (cte2.ID2_COMP = cte1.ID2) AND (cte2.ID1_COMP = cte1.ID1))
WHERE cte1.ID <> cte2.ID_COMP AND cte2.DENSE_RANK_COMP <= cte1.DENSE_RANK)
-- Any IDs that shows up in cte3 remove from the final result
SELECT data.*
FROM data
WHERE ID NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT ID FROM cte3)
ORDER BY data.ACT_TIME
```

Here's my create table

```
CREATE TABLE `data` (
    `ID` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `ID1` VARCHAR(10) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'latin1_swedish_ci',
    `ID2` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `ACT_TIME` TIMESTAMP NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `X` FLOAT(12) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `Y` FLOAT(12) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `Z` FLOAT(12) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`ID`) USING BTREE,
    INDEX `ID1` (`ID1`) USING BTREE,
    INDEX `ACT_TIME` (`ACT_TIME`) USING BTREE
);
```

Here's the EXPLAIN {query} result
[image]

Here's how the query should work.

I want to remove any rows (that have the same ID1 and ID2) that occur later on where X and Y are in between +-2 and a Z less than 1.2*z

Here's an example input

[image]

Example output

[image]

This query takes about 5min with 2.5M rows.

I am on MariDB 10.5.5

Any and all help is appreciated!

EDIT for Rick James here's your explain {query}
here is the explain result
[image]

Comment: Could you add the `EXPLAIN <query>;` output too?

Comment: Any idea what the query should do?

Comment: @jkavalik Added the result of the EXPLAIN

Comment: @GerardH.Pille gave an example table and what the output should be

Comment: Pictures?  Great!  Perhaps it's possible to extract some test data using OCR.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an optimized, bug-fixed query. [Fiddle for demonstration](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.5&fiddle=7c50a68784c975f6a940788115be0cb1).

```
WITH cte1 AS (
SELECT *, (X-2) AS X_START, (X+2) AS X_END, 
    (Y-2) AS Y_START, (Y+2) AS Y_END, (Z*1.2) AS Z_MAX,
    DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY ID1, ID2 ORDER BY ACT_TIME) AS `DENSE_RANK`
    FROM data
), 
cte3 AS (
SELECT 
c.ID
FROM cte1
JOIN cte1 c ON (cte1.ID <> c.ID and cte1.X_END >= c.X and c.X >= cte1.X_START
 and cte1.Y_END >= c.Y and c.Y >= cte1.Y_START and c.Z < cte1.Z*1.2 
 and c.`DENSE_RANK` > cte1.`DENSE_RANK`)
)
SELECT data.*
FROM data
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM cte3 where cte3.ID=data.ID)
ORDER BY data.ACT_TIME
```

Issues I addressed:

- Changed `WHERE NOT IN` to `WHERE NOT EXISTS`, `IN` with a large  list is a common performance issue.
- The optimizer noticed that `cte2` was entirely unnecessary, being simple column aliases, so I eliminated it and made `cte3` a strict self-join. `c` is the candidate row.
- The `Z_MAX` bound was missing the 1.2 coefficient. Your query returned 2 extra rows from your example output due to this being missing.
- Removed the `ORDER BY` in `cte1` as it was unnecessary.

The goal here was to get rid of as many sorts as possible and keep down the number of table scans. If your server has especially poor I/O performance it may be worth exploring memory tuning options to keep the sorts from spilling to disk.

PS: Rick James noticed that `ACT_TIME` could be used as a tiebreaker instead of `DENSE_RANK()` and if that works for your data then that would get rid of another sort.

Comment: Thank you, with your improvements (haven't done the ACT_TIME part yet) I was able to go from 280s -> 215s

Comment: For some reason when I remove the DENSE_RANK part the query doesn't seem to finish

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need CTEs.  See if something like this will work:

```
SELECT d1.*, d2.*
    FROM data d1
    JOIN data d2  ON d2.x BETWEEN d1.x - 2 AND d1.x + 2
                 AND d2.y BETWEEN d1.y - 2 AND d1.y + 2
                 AND d2.z ... (I don't understand the criteria here)
                 AND d2.act_time < d1.act_time
```

Indexes for the optimizer to pick among:

```
INDEX(x,y,z,act_time)
INDEX(y,z,x,act_time)
INDEX(z,x,y,act_time)
```

Meanwhile,  Remove the `(12)` from `FLOAT(12)`.

I don't see the explanation for whey `DENSE_RANK` is needed.

Comment: hmm I am not sure why, but when I try do this filter it just never finishes

Comment: @mike_gundy123 - OK.  Could you provide `EXPLAIN SELECT` for my version (and any future versions you review).   Also, what did you do about the d2.z test?  Oh, I seem to have lost an operator for act_time;fixing now.

Comment: ya I did AND d2.Z < d1.Z * 1.2

Comment: Added explain result in the post

Comment: @mike_gundy123 - Thanks for the Explain.  As I expected, tt shows a full scan (for d1) and a partial scan of d2.  However, It does not seem to have the 3 indexes I suggested.